# replace old Intel cpu (with pins) with the new generation

Tags: cpu, motherboard, intel-core-i7

I have HP Elitebook Workstation 8560w with Intel core I7 2860QM.

I want to upgrade it to the new I7 generation (at least 6th or the 5th), but I found some information online say that the old I7 generation was with Pins to connect to the motherboard socket, where the new one doesn't have them.

Is there a solution for this issue? "instead of buying new laptop ;)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While different generations of CPUs might have similar names (like 'i7') they typically are very different. It is not normally possible to replace a CPU with one that is of a newer generation, and it is never possible to replace it with one that is two or more generations newer.

This difference is not only a matter of different package layouts, but also a matter of different power inputs, other initialization phases and last but not least BIOS incompatibilities.

In short: You can't replace a 2860QM with a 5th or 6th Gen i7

Comment: Thanks. These information are new to me. So, I have to buy a news laptop :)